# Is the deviance statistic in an Analysis of Deviance table a chi squared statistic

Tags: r, anova, chi-squared-test, deviance

```
Analysis of Deviance Table

Model 1: Exercise ~ 1
Model 2: Exercise ~ WaketimeStand
  Resid. Df Resid. Dev Df Deviance Pr(>Chi)  
1       115     124.55                       
2       114     121.51  1   3.0351  0.08148 .
---
```

Simple question just to confirm  - is the deviance statistic in an Analysis of Deviance table the Chi squared value for the difference between the models?

To make things clearer I add this the code I wrote to get this output;

> anova(NullEx,ModEx7,test = "Chi")

Answer (score 0):

$$H_0: \text{The additional parameters in the more complex model are 0.}$$

$$H_a: H_0\text{ is false.}
$$

Under this setup, the test statistic has an asymptotic $\chi^2$ distribution, yes.

Comment: Would it therefore be correct to state Waketime standardised is non-significant (X2 = 3.0351, p =0.08148)

Comment: @chris1 It looks like the difference between models is just one parameter, which I suppose is Waketime. Your test is giving you a p-value of $0.08$-ish, which is not significant at the $0.05$-level.